# MongoDB Aggregation - Accessing lookup fields in project

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I access a lookup field in $project using $unwind but this breaks the accessibility of the other nested fields from the main collection. Is there any way to access the fields from both collections in $project. I thought of merging the arrays but still not sure if it's the right approach.

**Users collection**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a54f739fe0a00373e7ef1e8"),
"team" : {
    "name" : "test",
},
"updated_at" : ISODate("2018-05-22T04:28:00Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2018-01-09T17:09:13Z"),
"users" : [
    {
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-11-22T11:55:22Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2018-01-09T17:09:13Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a54f739fe0a00373e7ef1e9"),
        "name" : test,
        "status" : "active",
        "title" : "Engineer",
    },
    {
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-11-22T11:55:22Z"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2018-01-09T17:09:13Z"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a54f739fe0a00373e7ef1e9"),
        "name" : test1,
        "status" : "passive",
        "title" : "Tester",
    }
]
```

}

**Comments collection**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6062178fc73fe806e45c9b69"),
    "userId" : "5a54f739fe0a00373e7ef1e9",
    'text' : 'this is a test',
    "status" : "1",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2021-03-29T18:08:14.317Z")
}
```

**Pipeline**

```
$pipeline = [['$match' => [
            'users' => [
                '$elemMatch' => [
                    'field1' => $field1,
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ],
        ['$unwind' => '$users'],
        ['$match' => [
                'users.field1' => $field1,
            ]
        ],

        ['$addFields' => ['userId' => ['$toString' => '$userId' ]]],
        ['$lookup' => [
            'from' => 'comments',
            'localField' => 'userId',
            'foreignField' => 'userId',
            'as' =>  'userComments'
            ]
        ],
        ['$unwind' => '$userComments'],
        ['$project' => [
                'comments'  => [
                    '$switch'   => [
                        'branches'  => [
                            [ 'case' =>  [
                                '$eq'   => ['$userComments.status','verified']
                                ],
                                'then'  => 1],
                            [ 'case' =>  [
                                '$lte'   => ['$userComments.status', '']
                                ],
                                'then'  => 1],
                        ],
                        'default'   => 0
                    ]
                ],
                'status' => '$users.status',
                'total' => [false],
                
            ]
        ],

        ['$group' => [
                '_id' => $groupBy,
                'text' => ['$sum' => '$comments'],
                'total' => ['$sum' => '$total'],
                'completed' => ['$sum' => '$status'],
               
            
             ]
        ],
    ];
```

**result**

```
 {"_id" :"categories","text": 21,"total": 100,"completed":50}
```

Comment: please provide sample data and your prefer output data as JSON

Comment: @mohammadNaimi I added the sample data.

Comment: Instead of the first three stages, you may use the `$filter` operation to filter the `users`.